# Sync doesn't work as expected when table has two pivots and a compound primary key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
class ProjectEmployees extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {

        // employees assigned to each project
        Schema::create('project_employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer("project_id")->unsigned();
            $table->integer("employee_id")->unsigned();
            $table->tinyInteger("is_project_leader")->unsigned()->default(0);
            $table->tinyInteger("is_manager")->unsigned()->default(0);
        });


        Schema::table('project_employees', function($table) {


            $table->primary(['project_id', 'employee_id']);

            // FK
            $table->foreign('employee_id')->references('id')->on('employees');
            $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects');
        });

    }

}
```

I have a model for projects and another for employees. I want to be able to assign employees as project leaders and project managers. I have this method:

```
 function assignProjectLeaders($project, $employees)
    {    
        $syncData = $this->addPivotValue($employees, ['is_project_leader' => true]);
        $project->projectLeaders()->sync($syncData);           
    }

function addPivotValue($items, $pivotValues): array
{
    $pivotData = array_fill(0, count($items), $pivotValues);
    $syncData = array_combine($items, $pivotData);
    return $syncData;
}
```

So I want the method assignProjectLeaders to set the given employees as Project Leaders of the given project object. However if an employee is already associated to the project as project manager this doesnt work because of the primary key restriction (it seems to be trying to insert again the pair (project, employee) instead of just updating the is_project_leader column to 1).

Comment: Laravel does not support the compound primary key setup. In stead, you should try to re-introduce a plain id as primary key, and get the rest done by unique constraints like `$table->unique(['project_id', 'employee_id']);`. This way laravel can identify which pk to update, and you still have your uniqueness :)

Comment: Please post the `projectLeaders` relationship.